# A page appears to have been hacked, how do I find the code that's causing it?

Tags: redirect

I can't seem to find the JS code, I've tried searching the url in the source but can't seem to find anything that would explain the redirect. The page is automatically redirecting after one second of wait time.

Also, looks like it isn't possible to go to the previous page, which is odd.

Is there any way I can get the actual JS line that performs that redirection or is there something else that is causing this?

Comment: Post the code that was affected/exploited. I would first disable JS in your browser to verify it is a JS problem. If it is, open up the code in your favorite editor and press ctrl+f and search for the URL your being redirected to.

Comment: Looks like line 15 to me. Unless my psychic powers aren't working today.

Comment: Celeritas is right...how are we supposed to help you any, if we don't know what's going on? Furthermore, how was the 'page hacked'? Did someone get the password and changed the source of the page? A word of the wise: ALWAYS keep backups for cases like that.

Comment: @Celeritas I'm afraid the page is password protected, so this is not possible. Can you please refer to my actual question, which is: "Is there any way I can get the actual JS line that performs that redirection?"

Comment: @Lior are you the owner of the webpage or just a user? If you're a user then what makes you say it was hacked?

Comment: Furthermore: If you say JS is at fault for the redirect...and you are a user...simply deactivate JS for your browser and you'll be able to get through just fine...but be sure to alert the actual webmaster ;)

Comment: @Celeritas I am the owner of the webpage. Is there any other way to perform a redirect a second after the page has already loaded other than JS?

Comment: There is another way "<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="seconds;URL=the-other-url">" - see http://www.internetofficer.com/seo/html-redirect/

Comment: @Lior there are a few ways to use JS to do a redirect. You may want to look here http://ntt.cc/2008/01/21/5-ways-to-redirect-url-with-javascript.html

Comment: @hatchet Thanks, never crossed my mind! Please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to do a delayed redirect without using any javascript, using a meta tag.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="seconds;URL=the-other-url">
```

for example, this would redirect after 2 seconds...

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<!-- stuff here -->
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="2;URL=http://www.{somesite.com}/xxxxxx">
<!-- more stuff -->
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<!-- yet more stuff -->
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

You can read more about the tag here: http://www.internetofficer.com/seo/html-redirect/